# Creating an array of char pointers to eleven strings but having an issue with printing them

Tags: c, pointers

I'm attempting to create a program that takes an input of eleven strings or things to do and stores them in an array and I want to store them such that only the last byte for each string in storage is the null character. I then want to be able to press the enter key and have the program print randomly one of these items from the strings. However, I appear to be having a hard time with memory management as the first string being stored is never the string that I stored it is always junk. I was curious why this is the case and what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int num_string=11,k=0;
    char** list_of_strings;
    list_of_strings=malloc(4*11);
    
    
    while (num_string>0){
        int i=0;
        char* string;
        string=malloc(100);
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            scanf("%c",&string[i]);
            if(string[i]=='\n'){
                string[i]='\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        string=realloc(string,i+1);
        list_of_strings[k]=string;
        k++;
        num_string--;
        
    }


    char ch;
    while(1){
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch=='\n'){
            int rand_num=rand()%11;
            char*sel_string=list_of_strings[rand_num];
            while(*sel_string!='\0'){
                printf("%c",*sel_string);
                sel_string++;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `list_of_strings=malloc(4*11);` Don't use hard coded numbers like that. It seems you are assuming pointers are 4 bytes. That may or may not be true for your system. You may be  building a 64 bit binary where pointers are 8 bytes. Use `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: @kaylum that worked perfectly. thank you.

Comment: Please explain more about "I want to store them such that only the last byte for each string in storage is the null character." and your reasons for it.

Comment: If you found a solution please create an answer. You can even accept it.